# Font Identification Final Cut Pro 2007

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying the identify the font in the picture below. I'm pretty sure it was created in Final Cut Pro in 2007. I've tried using the font identification services here [What are the requirements for font identification questions?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366), there are not enough characters for the step through different character characteristics matchers, or when uploading an image they fail to identify individual characters, due to the characters being made up of multiple separate lines.

[image: Futile Games]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font is [Colonna](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/colonna-mt/) and can be found on myfonts.

Example:

[image: example image]